# Unity 3D: Coroutine weapon animation won't execute more than once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a telescoping spike weapon for a game I'm working on that works perfectly fine once, but won't fire again afterwards:

```
public void ExpandSequence()
{
    if (!mExpanding)
    {
        StartCoroutine(mExpand);
    }
        
}

private IEnumerator _ExpandSequence()
{
    mExpanding = true;
    mBaseGoal = transform.localPosition + mBaseDistance * Vector3.up;
    mConeGoal = mSpikeSections[5].localPosition + mConeDistance * Vector3.up;

    while (transform.localPosition.y > mBaseSpikeEnd || mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y > mCylinderEnd
        || mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y > mConeEnd)
    { //only using the first cylinder section in the condition since they all move the same distance
        
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, mBaseGoal, mSpeed);

        mSpikeSections[1].localPosition = mSpikeSections[2].localPosition = mSpikeSections[3].localPosition = 
            mSpikeSections[4].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition, Vector3.up * mCylinderDistance, mSpeed);

        mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition, mConeGoal, mSpeed);

        if (Mathf.Approximately(transform.localPosition.y, mBaseSpikeEnd) &&
            Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y, mCylinderEnd) &&
            Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y, mConeEnd))
        {
            mExpanding = false; //probably unnecessary
            transform.localPosition = mBaseGoal;
            mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = mConeGoal;

            yield break; //putting this here stops it from looping, but it still won't fire a second time
        }

        yield return null;
    }
    mExpanding = false;
}

public void CollapseSequence()
{
    if (!mCollapsing)
    {
        StartCoroutine(mCollapse);
    }
}

private IEnumerator _CollapseSequence()
{
    mCollapsing = true;
    mBaseGoal = transform.localPosition - mBaseDistance * Vector3.up;
    mConeGoal = mSpikeSections[5].localPosition - mConeDistance * Vector3.up;

    while (transform.localPosition.y < mBaseSpikeStart || mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y < mCylinderStart
        || mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y < mConeStart)
    { //only using the first cylinder section in the condition since they all move the same distance

        transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, mBaseGoal, mSpeed);

        mSpikeSections[1].localPosition = mSpikeSections[2].localPosition = mSpikeSections[3].localPosition =
            mSpikeSections[4].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition, Vector3.zero, mSpeed);

        mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition, mConeGoal, mSpeed);

        if (Mathf.Approximately(transform.localPosition.y, mBaseSpikeStart) && 
            Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y, mCylinderStart) && 
            Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y, mConeStart))
        {
            transform.localPosition = mBaseGoal;
            mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = mConeGoal;
            mCollapsing = false; //probably unnecessary
            yield break; //putting this here stops it from looping, but it still won't fire a second time
        }

        yield return null;
    }
    mCollapsing = false;
}
```

The if-statements I added at the end were for "damage control" but don't seem to change the general outcome. The expand helper function "Expand()" seems to execute every time, but the actual functions as well as the collapse helper function only run once. If anyone can help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you assign `mExpand` and `mCollapse`.

But I guess you did it only once e.g. in `Start`. It then happens only once because the assigned routine is already finished after the first run.

It should probably rather be e.g.

```
public void ExpandSequence()
{
    if (!mExpanding)
    {
        mExpand = StartCoroutine(_ExpandSequence());
    }
}
```

and accordingly also for the collapse routine in order to be running a **new** `IEnumerator`/`Coroutine` instead of the one that already ran to the end.

Comment: I did in fact assign them in the Start function. That's what I usually do, and this is the only time I've run into an issue like this. Also I tried your code but it's telling me you can't convert a coroutine into an IEnumerator

Comment: Ok then simply skip the `mExpand =` .. I thought you had stored it as a `Coroutine` not an `IEnumerator`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! For future reference, do you know why calling them by variable name gave me issues but calling the functions themselves worked fine?